# samsung android 8 and 8.1 - change keyboard programmatically

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I've problem, when change keyboard programmatically on Samsung S9 with android 8.0 and other samsung with Android 8.0 or 8.1
I haven't any problem on Huawei or other phones that I've tested with android 8.0 or 8.1.

In my EditText I've set onSelectionChanged method. 
I want change keyboard during the digitation.
In particular, the keyboard start in text mode, change in Number mode and next need to retun in text mode, so you make easy when digit plate (ex: AA123BB)

```
@Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);     
            if (selEnd > 1 && selEnd < 5) {
                if(getInputType() != InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER )
                    setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            } else {
                if(getInputType() != (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS ) )
                    setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
            }
}
```

When Keyboard return to TEXT type, you can see the symbols keyboard and not letters.
[You can find the result in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PIHt.png)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually supported.  There is no method to force a keyboard to change, and changing types on an already started input connection will not be supported by most keyboards.  There is no reliable way to do this.  setInputType is only guaranteed to work on the next time the keyboard is opened int hat field.

Comment: Yes, I know, but at the moment, on samsung  with Android 8.0 and 8.1 happen! I don't want that happen!